# Não consigo achar a biblioteca gráfica glew

Tags: opengl, library

O site da biblioteca GLEW estar fora do ar, http://glew.sourceforge.net/
Alguém conhece algum site onde eu possa baixar.
Eu até encontrei alguns porém não tem os arquivos que eu quero, que é o bin, o include e o lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procure sempre no Github quando não encontrar na sua busca preferida.

Muitos desenvolvedores migraram para lá para manter seus fontes ativas em comunidade.

Confira se é isto:
https://github.com/nigels-com/glew

Comment: Parece que eles mudaram para lá mesmo, mas não tem os arquivos que eu estava procurando, talvez eu tenha que compilar os arquivos que estão no GitHub. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Veja os links para download na pagina.
Binários Windows:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.1.0/glew-2.1.0-win32.zip/download

Comment: @gamedoido  a resposta ajudou? O problema foi resolvido? Se sim, marque a resposta como certa. Obrigado :)

Comment: Valeu @David Silva era esses arquivos mesmo que eu tava procurando.